# Grep N times from pipe using xargs

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, xargs

I have a file named input that contains a list of wikipedia or substring of wikipedia titles. I only want to print out the lines that are wikipedia titles, not the substring.

I have another file named wikititle that contains a list of all wikipedia titles. So I want to grep each line from input and if it matches with ^{string}$, I want to print out that line.

I came up with below command:

```
cat input | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'grep -q -w ^{}$ wikititle && { echo {}; }'
```

But it gives me an error of:

```
 xargs: command too long
```

How do I make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: BTW -- the most likely reason for your "command too long" here was using `-0` without your input *actually* being NUL-delimited. If your input was actually newline-delimited and you used `xargs -0`, then it would try to create a single command with every single filename in your file substituted into it at the same time (including the newline separators).

Comment: Have you tried passing `-l1` (lower case L then 1) to `xargs`?
And if your input is a regular text file, you don't want to use `-0`, that is usually meant to be fed from `find -print0`.

Comment: ...also, btw, why the `grep -q ... && echo`? Wouldn't leaving the `-q` off the `grep` have the same effect? If you want to ensure no more than one match, `-m 1` would do that.

Comment: Also, `^${foo}$` is not *at all* guaranteed to match `${foo}`. Think about what happens if `foo` contains square brackets, or question marks, or any other interesting regex characters.

Comment: Relevant: BashFAQ #36 - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036

Comment: @jamieguinan, I'd argue that there are considerably more places where NUL-delimited streams are encountered than `find -print0` alone; consider `/proc/*/environ` for an example. I'm also a habitual user of `printf '%s\0' "$@"` when needing to serialize an argument list to file (or likewise for an array). But yes, agreed that the OP probably doesn't have a NUL-delimited stream here. :)

Comment: Post sample input and expected output and and we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to print out lines which are found in both of two files is with `comm`:

```
comm -12 <(sort input) <(sort wikititle)
```

This is **vastly** more efficient than what you were trying to do: It runs only a single pass, and needs to store very little content in memory at a time (`sort` can have larger memory requirements, but the GNU implementation supports using disk-backed temporary storage).

---

Another much more efficient approach would be the following:

```
grep -F -x -f input wikititle
```

...this would run `grep` *only once*, using all the (newline-separated) strings given in `input`, against the contents of `wikititle`.

Using `grep -F` avoids treating arguments as regexes, so that even strings like `Foo [Bar]` will match themselves when fully anchored (with they wouldn't with a grep which treated `[Bar]` as a character class). Using `-x` requires full-line matches (thank you, @tripleee!).

---

...and, if you **really** wanted to use `xargs` and a whole bunch of separate `grep` calls and a shell-level `echo` for no good reason...

```
<input xargs bash -c \
  'for line; do grep -q -F -x -e "$line" wikititle && printf '%s\n' "$line"; done' _
```

Note that this doesn't use `-I '{}'`, which is an option which makes `xargs` far less efficient (forcing it to run a command once for every single match), and also introduces potential security bugs when used with `bash -c` (if a line in your input file contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, you probably don't want to execute it). Instead, it uses a `for` loop in your bash to iterate over filenames passed as arguments.

Comment: With `grep -x` you won't need the Awk preprocessing at all.

Comment: @tripleee, excellent, thanks! That lets me change to `grep -F`, thus avoiding the correctness issues implicit in the prior approach.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample input and expected output it's a guess but it sounds like all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{titles[$0];next} $0 in titles' wikititle input
```

Remember that shell is an environment from which to manipulate files and processes and invoke tools, NOT a tool to manipulate text. The guys who created shell also created awk for shell to call to manipulate text.

Comment: Eh. The guy who created ksh, from early versions of which the POSIX sh spec was inspired, very much intended it to be performant and capable enough to do computation (inclusive of text processing) in its own right. The historical authorities aren't unambiguously aligned here. :)

Comment: ...though as we both fully agree that tools external to the shell are the Right Thing for this particular task, I don't know why I'm bothering to debate the line of argument used. The reason I'd argue `comm` is often a better tool for this task than `awk` is memory usage -- needing to load one of the two files' contents into a hash table may or may not be workable.

Comment: I'm not trying to suggest you can't do text processing in shell. Obviously you CAN do it, it's just a really bad idea since what shell does by default is NOT what you want to do when processing text (e.g. expanding escape chars and stripping white space from the front/back of lines when reading them) and so it's very difficult to get the code correct and the end result is always extremely slow compared to, say, awk. `comm` with a couple of `sort`s and some bash process substitution is fine for this task but how does comm work if not by loading the files into memory?

Comment: I wouldn't call typing `IFS= read -r line` "very" difficult. And as for "always extremely slow", that's true for bash or dash, and most 3rd-party ksh clones, but not genuine David Korn ksh93.

Comment: ...and if `comm` had to load things into memory, why do you think they'd need to be sorted? The whole point of requiring sorted inputs is to not need to store more than one line from each input file at a time (though as modern `comm` provides out-of-order detection, it typically will store at least two). I could show the algorithm on a whiteboard trivially; it's not worth my time to type it in a text box.

Comment: No one thing is difficult, it's the sum of them that's hard to get right (add in `echo $line` when the input file contains a `*`, keeping track of line numbers, etc.. - all completely programmable in shell but provided for you by awk) and the key point is that tools that are designed to do text processing have default behaviors and functionality that make sense for text processing. You can write an awk script to sequence calls to shell tools but it's clunky and messy and requires careful coding because that's not what awk is for, it's what shell is for.

Comment: Something somewhere is storing the results of the 2 `sorts`. If not comm then bash. Either way memory is being used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100851/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ed-morton).

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. We both know what we're doing, we both understand everything we're both saying, and we could talk about this for hours and it wouldn't change anything about our opinions which FWIW I don't think are really very different.

Comment: There are some distinctions (no, there actually *isn't* storage of the results of the two `sort`s), which I made in chat. Agreed, though, that we're quibbling over details and agree on the broad swaths.